# "Triangle" inequality for integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, inequality

I have got two questions:

1) Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be any continuous function. Let $\Gamma$ be a piecewise smooth curve on $\mathbb{R}^2$. The following inequality holds:
$$\left|\int_{\Gamma}f(x,y)\, \mathrm{d}s\right|\le \int_{\Gamma}\left|f(x,y)\right|\ |\mathrm{d}s|$$

My question if how do we interpret $|\mathrm{d}s|$? Why it is not just $\mathrm{d}s$? Is it connected to the fact that when we plug in parametrization of that curve, then this inequality holds only if we take absolute value of Jacobian?

2) Why do we define line integrals only for piecewise smooth curves?

Comment: $|ds|$ is the length of how the vector $s$ is changing, usually $s$ is a vector and $ds$ would also be a vector.  Piecewise smooth curves are most curves that you'll come across (curves which are not piecewise smooth are very messy).

Comment: @MichaelBurr Why don't you write that as an answer so the op can accept it? :)